# Node JS Cannot Get /

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am following [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2) Node JS tutorial, but I have encountered a problem where I get the response `Cannot GET /` instead of `Hello`. Here is the structure for my code:

```
myapp/
├── app
│   └── routes
│       ├── index.js
│       └── note_routes.js
├── conf
│   ├── httpd-app.conf
│   └── httpd-prefix.conf
├── htdocs
├── node_modules
│   ├── ...
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── server.js
```

`server.js` looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

`index.js` is this:

```
const noteRoutes = require('./note_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  noteRoutes(app, db);
  // Other route groups could go here, in the future
};
```

And `note_routes.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    // You'll create your note here.
    res.send('Hello')
  });
};
```

As can be seen, this is a very simple setup. According to the above-linked tutorial, this should be enough and should respond with `Hello`. However, this is not the case.

I am almost 100% sure that the port is correct because there is *some* not-503 response.

What's wrong here, and how can I get this to work as intended?

Comment: you have to use POST and not GET

Comment: @DZDomi, does `app.post(...)` in `note_routes.js` not do that? Where did I use get?

Comment: change the app.post line to app.get and you can call it from your browser

Comment: or if you are using postman (used in the tutorial) you have to change the  HTTP Method in the dropdown from GET to POST (depending on what you want)

Comment: and learn the different http methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: Show us how you sent your post request in Postman. It looks like you might be hitting your base url instead of /notes

Comment: @stone, that is exactly what was happening indeed. Once I selected the POST option it worked. Earlier, I was using Safari not Postman and was just putting in a URL. What would the normal URL look like for POST with no parameters?

Comment: the url is independent of the used HTTP Method. You can have 2 different endpoints with the same url, but with different http methods eg;
GET /notes => returns all inserted notes
POST /notes => creates a new note in your database

Answer (score 0):

Your app.post() in note_routes should be app.get() or if you plan on making post requests then you can chain it like

```
app.post()
   .get();
```

Comment: [Here](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*pqIRP6BQSrVCCc6XVPZxPg.png) is an image from the tutorial detailing the way I'm supposed to interact with that code in Postman. What are they doing that I am not?

Comment: It should work with post. Post can return response data.

Comment: @stone, OHH that was a stupid mistake. I did not realize that the type of message was post not get. Nor did I realize post can return data

Comment: the error was could not GET/ meaning you made a GET request.

Comment: @RickyM, how can I turn the URL into a POST request? Postman simply needs me to select that option, but what is the actual URL it is using when I do that?

Comment: you can't post from the url, the url uses get requests only, so either with html forms, javascripts/ajax, and clients like postman or fidler that can add the required POST method to the request will be the only way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: every request (expect HEAD method) can return response data; the only difference is that, when you make a request GET can not have a body, POST can

Comment: @RickyM, thank you now I know why that didn't work. I see I wasted a lot of time trying to do something impossible

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong on a whole new kind of level.

I would imagine you are starting your server with `node server.js`

firstly, server.js does not require index.js anywhere

note_routes should contain .get() NOT .post()

in your browser you should be visiting http://localhost:3000/notes NOT plain old
http://localhost:3000